# Some questions about posix_memalign

Tags: c++, memory

I learned that you create a place on the heap with "new" and you have to explicitly release it with "delete" on Windows OS. But now I have to do it on Linux OS. I just have no idea.
for example

```
char str[] = new char[512];
delete[] char;
```

What should I do for Linux OS? I guess I should use posix_memalign but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: How on earth did you stumble upon `posix_memalign` looking for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code is neither valid C nor valid C++.

Perhaps you mean:

```
 char str* = new char[512];
 delete[] str;
```

which is valid C++ (not C, because `new` and `delete` are C++ keywords, not C ones) and works on Linux as it does on Windows or any standard C++ implementation.

Then, the `str` is allocated in the [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) (and the same program is allocating in the heap both on Windows and on Linux).

There is no need for [posix_memalign(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) (please look at the man page I just linked) in your case.

You could want to use `posix_memalign` if for some particular reason you wanted the pointer to be aligned, e.g. be a multiple of 1024.

<sup>This example is silly on purpose, because it asks an alignment of 1024 bytes for a memory zone of 512 bytes.</sup>

Then please have

```
 #define _GNU_SOURCE
 #include <new>
 #include <stdlib.h>
```

and later in the same C++ source file:

```
 char* str = NULL;
 void* ad = NULL;
 if (posix_memalign(&ad, 1024, 512)) 
    { perror("posix_memalign failed"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
 str = new(ad) char[512];
```

but you should have some particular reason to want an aligned pointer (here, a multiple of 1Kbyte). Usually you don't want pointer to be aligned more than the default. (You may require a large alignment, e.g. if doing arithmetic on `(intptr_t)` casts of your pointers; but this is very unusual). Notice the [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_new) (provided by the `<new>` standard header).

I recommend reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (which is more focused on C than on C++). And always compile on Linux with all warnings requested by the compiler and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Learn to use the `gdb` debugger and the `valgrind` memory leak detector. Once your program has no bugs, consider asking the compiler to optimize its produced object code with `g++ -Wall -O2` instead of `g++ -Wall -g`.

actually, the real [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) done by your application to the [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) (whose list is on [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) for memory management are [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and `munmap(2)` (and perhaps `sbrk(2)` which is nearly obsolete). You should use the `strace` command to find out the many syscalls done by a process.

Comment: Ahh, I am trying to build a scanner for my compiler(a homework in fact ^^). My professor said we should use posix_memalign for our buffer. I thought that is because it is linux standard.

Comment: Do as you teacher requires. `posix_memalign` is not Linux specific, it is defined in the POSIX standard. But there are few good reasons to require a largely aligned buffer....

Comment: The sbrk syscall is not in danger of being obsolete. It was never intended to be called from high level languages (like C) to allocate memory. It is used by the runtime libraries to request more memory from Linux. It is where the runtime libraries normally find space to satisfy small requests for memory by library functions like malloc.

Comment: @Carlos Reyes AFAIK, recent `malloc`  implementations are phasing out `sbrk`  in favor of `mmap`. There are technical reasons (think of multithreading) to do so

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sure, that makes sense. I just do not see sbrk going away anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `new[]` and `delete[]` are C++ constructs, not C.

They are available on any compliant platform, so you can use them on Linux.

Note that your syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
char *str = new char[512];
delete[] str;
```

If you are coding in C rather than C++, you can use `malloc()` and `free()`.